# How to run a python script (which is hosted on a different server), with another ppython script?

Tags: python

I'm trying to run a Python script which is hosted on a different server. I have access to both servers. I've tried to use an Apache server with a php script which runs the python script and returns the output, using `shell_exec()`. But it seems like its capping at 100 (while I can still run the file myself when logged in as root). My question about that is right here: https://serverfault.com/questions/1017357/centos-php-processes-limited-with-shell-exec.

Is there another way to run the Python script which is hosted on my server, from another python script on my pc?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Wrapping the Python script in a PHP script is just crazy; Python itself is perfectly capable of rwnning CGI / WSGI / web apps. What exactly and how exactly depends on the nature of your script; trivially, configure your web server to run Python scripts just like you previously configured it to run PHP..

Answer (score 0):

Either you can use `subprocess.call` module which will run it as a child process or you can use something like this.

(This is to run python from a file. You may modify it accordingly to download it and run)

```
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        code = compile(f.read(), file, 'exec')
        exec(code)
```

Comment: Thanks for the repsonse! I don't want to download the file on the server. As that script has to be secret, users need to be able to receive the outcome from the server

Comment: In that case, I think `subprocess` module should work fine for you. You can read about it here: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/subprocess.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this

```
from subprocess import run, PIPE
import sys

run([sys.executable,"python_script_location"],shell = False, stdout = PIPE)
```